# Save data from different models into one table SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have 3 drop down list that I populate it from 3 different models, and then I try to save the choices in one SQL table.

This is the controller where i populate the drop down list and where i try to save the data to database:

```
        public AttivitaController(AppDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        //populate first drop down list
        private List<Cliente> GetCLienti()
        {
            var tuttiClienti = _db.tboClienti.ToList();
            return tuttiClienti;
        }

        //populate second drop down list
        private List<Tecnico> GetTecnici()
        {
            var tuttiTecnici = _db.tboTecnici.ToList();
            return tuttiTecnici;
        }
        
        //populate third drop down list
        private List<SottoCliente> GetSottoCLienti()
        {
            var tuttiSottoClienti = _db.tboSottoClienti.ToList();
            return tuttiSottoClienti;
        }

        public IActionResult CreareAttivita()
        {
            ViewBag.Tecnici = GetTecnici();
            ViewBag.Clienti = GetCLienti();
            ViewBag.SottoClienti = GetSottoCLienti();
            return View();
        }

        //This is how I tried to save data into database
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreareAttivita(Tecnico tecnico, Cliente cliente, SottoCliente sottoCliente)
        {
            int idTecnico = 0;
            int idCLiente = 0;
            int idSottoCliente = 0;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.Form["ddlTecnico"]))
                idTecnico = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ddlTecnico"]);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.Form["ddlClienti"]))
                idCLiente = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ddlClienti"]);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.Form["ddlSottoCliente"]))
                idSottoCliente = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ddlSottoCliente"]);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                tecnico.Id = idTecnico;
                cliente.Id = idCLiente;
                sottoCliente.Id = idSottoCliente;
                _db.Add(tecnico);
                _db.Add(cliente);
                _db.Add(sottoCliente);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

`if (ModelState.IsValid)`  is allways false, I can't get why!
This is model Attivita :

```
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Seleziona un tecnico!")]
        public int Id_tecnici { get; set; }

        public int Id_clienti { get; set; }

        public int Id_sotto_clienti { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Commessa")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Manca la parte della commessa!")]
        public string Commessa { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Descrizione")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Inserisci descrizione!")]
        public string Descrizione { get; set; }

        public string Nota { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Data inizio")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Inserisci data inizio")]
        public DateTime Data_inizio { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Data fine")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Inserisci data fine")]
        public DateTime Data_fine { get; set; }
```

This are the drop down list:

```
            <div class="col text-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    @*Lista Tecnici*@
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        @Html.DropDownList("ddlTecnico", new SelectList(ViewBag.Tecnici, "Id", "Nome"), "Seleziona Tecnico", new { @id = "ddlTecnico", @class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle  mr-3" })
                    </div>
                    @*Lista Clienti*@
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        @Html.DropDownList("ddlClienti", new SelectList(ViewBag.Clienti, "Id", "Nome_azienda"), "Seleziona Azienda", new { @id = "ddlClienti", @class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle  mr-3" })
                    </div>
                    @*Lista Sotto Clienti*@
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        @Html.DropDownList("ddlSottoCliente", new SelectList(ViewBag.SottoClienti, "Id", "Azienda"), "Seleziona Sotto Cliente", new { @id = "ddlSottoCliente", @class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle  mr-3" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

When I submit the data it gaves me error :

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vkpQ.png)

[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'items')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjWlG.png)
I can't understand why `ddlTecnico` is null

Any suggestion how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
 private List<SelectListItem> GetCLienti()
    {
        var tuttiClienti = _db.tboClienti.Select(x =>
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Id,
                Text = a.Nome
            }).ToList();
        return tuttiClienti;
    }
```

do so with two other methods.
After that change in view

```
 <div class="col text-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
                @*Lista Tecnici*@
                <div class="dropdown">
                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlTecnico", ViewBag.Tecnici, "Seleziona Tecnico", new { @id = "ddlTecnico", @class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle  mr-3" })
                </div>
                @*Lista Clienti*@
                <div class="dropdown">
                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlClienti", ViewBag.Clienti, "Seleziona Azienda", new { @id = "ddlClienti", @class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle  mr-3" })
                </div>
                @*Lista Sotto Clienti*@
                <div class="dropdown">
                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlSottoCliente",ViewBag.SottoClienti, "Seleziona Sotto Cliente", new { @id = "ddlSottoCliente", @class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle  mr-3" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

In the end

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.Form["ddlTecnico"]))
            idTecnico = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ddlTecnico"].ToString());
```

Reference that can help you https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/select-lists

Comment: `if (ModelState.IsValid)`  is allways false. I update my question with code of model `Attivita`

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your error,when running `return View();` in your post method ,it will return CreareAttivita.cshtml.But in the post method,you didn't intialize `ViewBag.Tecnici`,`ViewBag.Clienti`and `ViewBag.SottoClienti`.So you need to add`ViewBag.Tecnici = GetTecnici();ViewBag.Clienti = GetCLienti();ViewBag.SottoClienti = GetSottoCLienti();`.

Here is a demo worked:

Controller:

```
public IActionResult CreareAttivita()
        {
            List<Tecnici> list = new List<Tecnici> { new Tecnici { Id = "1", Nome = "Tecnici1" }, new Tecnici { Id = "2", Nome = "Tecnici2" }, new Tecnici { Id = "3", Nome = "Tecnici3" }};
            ViewBag.Tecnici=list;
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreareAttivita(Tecnici tecnici) {
            List<Tecnici> list = new List<Tecnici> { new Tecnici { Id = "1", Nome = "Tecnici1" }, new Tecnici { Id = "2", Nome = "Tecnici2" }, new Tecnici { Id = "3", Nome = "Tecnici3" } };
            ViewBag.Tecnici = list;
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="dropdown">
        @Html.DropDownList("ddlTecnico", new SelectList(ViewBag.Tecnici, "Id", "Nome"), "Seleziona Tecnico", new { @id = "ddlTecnico", @class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle  mr-3" })
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Tecnici:

```
public class Tecnici
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: How to fix that ?

Comment: `if (ModelState.IsValid)`  is allways false. I update my question with code of model `Attivita`

Comment: Firstly,the error`the value cannot be null`, I said in my answer you can use `ViewBag.Tecnici = GetTecnici();ViewBag.Clienti = GetCLienti();ViewBag.SottoClienti = GetSottoCLienti();.` before return page.And then you said the code 'if (ModelState.IsValid)' is always false.But I don't know the code of model `Tecnico`, `Cliente`,` SottoCliente` in post method.